# How to update product stock using custom script in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, stock

How to create a script for update product stock.
After the product stock update saves the product.
Anyone helps me to create this script.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code in your phtml.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productId = 1; // Your Product ID
$_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
$_product->setStockData(array(
        'qty' => 300 //your Qty
    )
);
$_product->save();
```

I just tried it works. !!

Comment: We want this from custom phtml file

Comment: @Anil I have updated my answer, try this one.

Answer (score 0):

Below I have write simple code for update product stock.

```
    <?php

namespace Agtech\Productstockupdate\Block\Index;


class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    protected $productFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    }

    public function updateStock($productId,$productQty)
    {
        $product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($productId);

        $product->setStockData(
            [
                'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
                'manage_stock' => 1, //manage product stock
                'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
                'qty' => $productQty, //QTY
            ]
        );
        $product->save();
    }

}
```

open your Phtml file and call this function `$block->updateStock($productId,$productQty). like $block->updateStock(10,100)`
Run Cammand

Comment: We want this functionality using phtml file. When we run this file in front side then product stock update.

Comment: @Anil Create block file into you module and add above code after that call updateStock function into phtml file . like $block->updateStock($productId,$productQty). I have edited code

Comment: We don't clear what you say. because of we are not more familiar with coding.

Comment: please give your phtml file path and module name. Also give block name and path if you have

Comment: Module Name => Agtech/Productstockupdate

Phtml file path =>
app/code/Agtech/Productstockupdate/view/frontend/templates/productstockupdate_index_index.phtml

Comment: Also plz give your app/code/Agtech/Productstockupdate/view/frontend/layout file name and code where your call productstockupdate_index_index.phtml

Comment: Layout file Name => productstockupdate_index_index.xml

Code =>

<referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Agtech\Productstockupdate\Block\Index\Index" name="productstockupdate_index_index" template="Agtech_Productstockupdate::productstockupdate_index_index.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>

Comment: I have Edited code, Just Copy above code and past into your block file Agtech\Productstockupdate\Block\Index\Index.php .  open your  Phtml file  => app/code/Agtech/Productstockupdate/view/frontend/templates/productstockupdate_index_index.phtml and call this function $block->updateStock($productId,$productQty). like $block->updateStock(10,100). Run Cammand

Comment: OKay I will update it. After check update you.

Comment: Run All cammand

Comment: We run all command. And put Block file code as per you provide. Also <?php
$block->updateStock(704,10) ?> in phtml file.in this code 704 is my product id & 10 is product quantity. But product quantity not update.

Comment: @Anil I have cross check it's working for me . could you check block function is calling or not . put log code into block function and check log .

Comment: Brother what you say; i don't understand. We create custom module using silk software. so I think default file calling functionality has no any issue.

Comment: @Anil . Add log into updateStock function and check var/log

Comment: We create log as per 'http://www.blogtreat.com/create-custom-log-file-magento-2/' this. but not generate any log file in var/log folder.

Comment: We get error in front 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE)  in Block/Index/Index.php

Comment: Could you show block code. it might be space issue . We are using $this variable two place 1) $this->productFactory = $productFactory; 2) $product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($productId); check code proper

Comment: Let's we talk via mail.

Comment: Check you email and run command

Comment: Add your changes & run all command but not update quantity in admin.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95047/discussion-on-answer-by-shorabh-how-to-update-product-stock-using-custom-script).